# Cycling through data without waiting for callback result with async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cursor

I need to write code that:

- Goes through data using a cursor
- Each item is an email to be sent: it will run sendMessage() wich will try and send the email
- If sendMessage() calls the callback with an error, I want to cycle to stop.
- BUT! I don't want the cycle to stop till sendMessage is done.

This is what I did:

```
    var messageTo;
    async.doWhilst(

      function( callback ){
        var errInCycle = null;

        // This function will return the next object, OR
        // null if the cursor is finished.
        cursor.next( function( err, i ){
          if( err ) return callback( err );

          messageTo = i;

          // If messageTo is null, just return. This is here because
          // cursor.next WILL return 'null' to indicate the last one
          if( messageTo === null ) return callback( null );

          // ******************************************
          // THIS IS WHERE EACH MESSAGE IS EVALUATED
          // ******************************************                  

          // Get the config for that message from the application
          getTransportConfig( messageTo, function( err, transportConfg ){
            if( err ){
              errInCycle = err;
              return;
            } 
            // Send the message!
            // This will only ever return with err !== null when something goes horribly wrong.
            // Undeliverable messages and minor errors won't return err
            sendMessage( transportConfig.transport, stores, messageTo, transportConfig.config, function( err ){
              if( err ){
                errInCycle = err;
              }

            });
          });

          // This is in the right spot! This cycle doesn't wait for sendMessage() to finish.
          // Calls the callback. at this point, errInCycle might have been set by one
          // of the callbacks above -- in which case, the cycle will interrupt
          callback( errInCycle );

        });
      },

      // Cycle will continue as long as this is true at the end of each iteration
      function(){ return messageTo != null; },

      // This is execute by async at the end of the cycle, when the previous function returns false
      function( err ) {

        inCycle = false; 
        if( err ){
          logger.log( { error: err, system: true, logLevel: 3, message: "Error while cycling through messages to send. CRON interrupted!", data: { config: config, messageTo: messageTo } } );
        }
        debug( "CRON DONE!" );
        return; 
      }
    );
```

Basically, I set `errInCycle` asynchronously; if there is a *bad* error, I want the cycle to stop -- and it will at the next iteration.

Does it look sane? Is there something I am missing? I am asking because it's not a pattern I have used before, and it seems like the only real solution to what I want to do.